# How can get some specific part from a column?

Tags: r

I have a csv file about IPC data. 
It's look like

```
year date applicant ... ipc number 
1978 1/1  noel          A43B 13/20 
1979 2/2  liam          B06C 14/20 
1980 3/3  chris         D01E 01/30 
...
```

For example,
I need `'A43B','B06C','D01E'` of `ipc` number
but not `'A43B 13/20', 'B07C 14/20', 'D01E 01/30'`

Could you please let me know how to deal with it?

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you search on SO for "string split", "string match" or similar term?

Comment: I suggest you start by typing `?strsplit` or `example(strsplit)` in the console. It's important that you try to read the doc. Then continue with `strsplit("abc 123", " ")`. One step at a time

Comment: `help.search("split")` yeilds some interesting results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad hoc I think there are two possibilities: 
1. As Pascal wrote go for strsplit and sapply

```
sapply(
 strsplit(c("A43B 13/20", "B06C 14/20", "D01E 01/30"),split = " "), 
"[[", 1)
```

2. Use regular expressions and the function gsub

```
gsub(pattern = " [0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}", replacement = "", c("A43B 13/20", "B06C 14/20","D01E 01/30"))
```

Comment: what does the "[[" , 1 mean?? sorry

Comment: strsplit returns a list. so you have to index the list to get the part you want. For example list[[1]] returns the first list element but in your case you want to have the first element of the first list element this works with the following command list[[1]][1] but you want to have for every list element the first element. This can done via sapply withe the command above "[[" means go in each list element and with the number you control which element of the list element shoud be retruned. Hopefully it is clear otherwise look for lapply / sapply addionally.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`.  We match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by one of more characters (`.*`) to the end (`$`) of the string and replace with `''`.

```
sub('\\s+.*$',  '', str1)
#[1] "A43B" "B07C" "D01E"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('A43B 13/20', 'B07C 14/20', 'D01E 01/30')
```